# Formatting loop output

Tags: powershell

I have the following code:

```
$versionList = "Windows 2000","Windows XP","Windows Vista","Windows 7","Windows 8","Windows Server 2003","Windows Server 2008","Windows Server 2008 R2","Windows Server 2012","Windows Server 2012 R2"

for($i = 0;$i -ne 10;$i++){
    $versionCheck = Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Property * | select OperatingSystem | where {$_.OperatingSystem -match $versionList[$i]}
       if($i -eq 0){
           Write-Host "Clients:" -for Green
       }
       if($i -eq 5){
           Write-Host "Servers:" -for Green
       }
    Write-Host $versionList[$i] `t $($versionCheck.OperatingSystem).Count 
}
```

This gives the following output:

```
Clients:
Windows 2000     0
Windows XP   0
Windows Vista    0
Windows 7    0
Windows 8    0
Servers:
Windows Server 2003      0
Windows Server 2008      0
Windows Server 2008 R2   0
Windows Server 2012      1
Windows Server 2012 R2   0
```

The numbers for the Server based Operating systems line up fine. The clients not so much. I would normally format this into a table but as the variables get renewed every time the loop runs that would make a lot of tables. How would I go abouts to format this properly?

Comment: Did you try -ft option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can format your output by using string formatting like this:

```
Write-Host ("{0,-22} {1,5}" -f $versionList[$i],$($versionCheck.OperatingSystem).Count)
```

Comment: Works like a charm. How does this work though? What does "{0,-22} {1,5}" -f indicate?

Comment: The first component between the curly braces references the parameter, 0 =  $versionList[$i] and 1 =  $($versionCheck.OperatingSystem).Count. The second component specifies the alignment (- = left alignment, + = right alignment). For more info, see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd%28v=VS.90%29.aspx